# Erro ao compilar meu arquivo TypeScript: error TS5011

Tags: javascript, typescript

Meu código no say.ts arquivo:

```
function say(person) {
    return "Hello" + person;
}

var user = "Gabriel Lemos";

console.log(say(user));
```

Quando eu tentei compilar:

> tsc say.ts

Eu tive o erro: path\say.js(1,1): error TS5011: Emit Error: Falha ao gravar no arquivo..

Comment: Tentou de novo? Isto é falha no ambiente não no código.

Comment: Eu tentei pelo VSCode, tentei rodar o tsc pelo cmd, pelo powershell. Não sei como tentar compilar

Comment: Você tem permissão para salvar?

Comment: Era realmente falta de permissão, alterei o path do arquivo para Downloads e compilou corretamente.